# É possível renomear um projeto java web usando o Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, ide

O Netbeans oferece a opção de renomear um projeto, já fiz isso várias vezes, inclusive o projeto e sua pasta e todas as vezes foram bem sucedidas. Todavia eram projetos Java SE, quando tento renomear um projeto Java web não consigo.

Quando tento renomear o projeto é aberta uma janela de opção chamada "Renomear Projeto" e eu marco a opção "Renomear Também a Pasta do Projeto" mas mesmo assim o projeto não é renomeado. Se eu desmarco a opção ele renomeia o projeto mas não a sua pasta.

Já procurei na documentação da IDE e em alguns lugares da internet e nada! Tentei renomear o projeto, mas o Netbeans abre a janela eu coloco o novo nome então ele começa o processo e logo em seguida diz que não pode renomear o projeto e apresenta uma janela com o erro:

> ERRO: Não é possivél renomear o arquivo TESTE em 
>   C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ para 
>   TESTE_SimpleJspServletDB.

Para renomear o projeto tenho que deletar o antigo criar um novo e copiar os arquivos do projeto para o novo projeto, isso diminui bastante a produtividade! Fico imaginando os motivos pelos quais esse processo não é bem sucedido! Penso que o servidor Tomcat fica rodando enquanto a IDE tenta renomear o projeto, mas não tenho certeza.

Comment: O netbeans renomeia o projeto java web mas  não a Pasta do Projeto onde ele esta! Para fazer isso tenho que fechar o IDE e renomear maunalmente.

Comment: exato pode renomar manualmente o nome da pasta

Comment: Era exatamente isso que eu queria evitar Skywalker!!

Comment: porque @Wellington Lins?

Comment: As vezes  você tem dezenas de projetos no diretório do netbeans mas que não estão abertos  na IDE , e  para renomear o projeto em questão  você  ´so pode fazer com a IDE fechada !! Isso faz você perder produtividade!!

Comment: Sei lá, não é sempre que renomeamos o nome de um projeto, então nao vejo isso como perder produtividade. Se você nao quer fechar a IDE, apenas clique com o botão direito encima do nome do projeto e tem a opção `fechar`, renomeie manuamente o nome da pasta e manda abrir novamente pelo netbeans, assim você nao fecha o netbeans

Comment: Claro sei que isso não é muito comum!! Mas vez por outra faço isso!! Muito boa a dica obrigado!!!!  E não dá bronca?

Comment: Quando tentei fazer isso com o  ntebeans aberto  ele abre a velha janela dizendo que a ação não pode ser concluída porque o projeto esta aberto em outro programa!!! Pode?

Comment: Mas você chegou a fechar o projeto no netbeans?

Comment: Sim, claro, Sim senhor!!!

Comment: Faça por favor um teste!!!

Comment: Aqui consegui fazer tudo pelo netbeans. Nem precisei renomear manualmente. Consegui renomear mesmo com o servidor iniciado

Comment: Então meu betbeans esta bugado eu já andava suspeitando!!! Sera que isso acontece porque eu trabalho com dois jdks 7 e o 8?

Comment: Skywalker a  sua versão do netbeans é completa? Ou é uma daquelas versões mais leves?

Comment: Netbeans 8.0.2 completa